# Rails 6 passanger error log - expected file to define constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I got this error in passanger error log:

```
expected file /var/www/my_app/app/controllers/categoriesnames.rb to define constant 
Categoriesnames, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
```

categoriesnames.rb

```
class CategoriesNamesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!



# Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
def categoriesnames_params
    params.require(:categoriesname).permit(

                                    :categories_name,
                                    :strona_id,
                                    :category_id
                                    
                                   )
    end


end
```

PS. it works on localhost

Comment: It doesn't actually work in development - the error is just popping up in production due to class eager loading. The error is pretty self evident - the file is named `categoriesnames.rb` and the constant `CategoriesNamesController`. You need to clean up your code and follow the naming conventions if you want to prevent these kind of slop errors.  It should be `categories_names_controller.rb` and `category_names` everywhere else.